# Intellij Idea (without maven) - cannot access javax.servlet.jsp.JspException

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have got problem like this:

```
Error:(53, 17) java: cannot access javax.servlet.jsp.JspException
  class file for javax.servlet.jsp.JspException not found
```

I,m using Intellij Idea *without* Maven. I have added `servlet-api.jar` to libraries, but it still doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add a `jsp-api.jar` to your build path. This jar contains the classes in the  `javax.servlet.jsp.*` packages,

A jar is available here:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.2/

Make sure you use the correct version.